# Android Kotlin reference or import library class from one module to another

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

Say I have two modules. **Module A** and **Module B**. Lets assume **Module A** is my app module and I have a library dependency called **myLib** which has a class called **LibClass**, Say I find my self needing to reference **LibClass** in **Module B**.

What is the recommended approach to do this? I am currently adding **myLib** again as a dependency in **Module B** that way I get a reference of **LibClass** in **Module B**.

I'd like to achieve this without needing to declare the library twice in Gradle (For **Module A** and **Module B**).

I also have a feeling this approach may be problematic.

Is there an effective way to go about it?

Comment: What problems are you anticipating? This sounds like the clearest, simplest, and least error-prone way to do this.

Comment: I have stuck with that approach. Fairly new to Android development.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle both as separate modules (folders), each with their own build gradle file.

if you want to reference the lib (Module B) to the app (module A) add

```
implementation project(':your-lib-module-name');
```

to have both in the file explorer/editor, create a settings file with the code

```
include ':your-module-name'
project(':your-module-name').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 'Library-name')
```

Note that you can't reference module A to module B, and Module B to module A at the same time, because will cause a circular reference.

Comment: I have stuck with declaring the library twice. For whatever I thought that it would be problematic I haven't run into any issues at all. I thought by declaring the dependency twice, I would be working with two separate instances from the point of declaration/instantiation. I basically built a singleton wrapper in one module, then consumed it in the other module, this consuming module handles its own responsibility.

Comment: Will definitely have a go at the recommendation. please note, fairly new to android and I am trying to wrap my mind how dependencies work in android compared to other technologies in Web Development, Hybrid apps......  And yes there is a thing called circular dependency, I am aware of it.